# Aggregate records by year and compute bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to aggregate records by year in a dataframe and create (and save) a barchart for each of them.

Using my rudimentary python I create a dictionary grouping by year

```py
dd = [x for _, x in df.groupby('year')]
```

The result is a dictionary ranging 0 to 55, which I can use to manually create a barchart. Of course I tried to create a basic loop to compute (and save) a barchart for each year

```py
i = 0
for i in dd:
    i =+ 1
    title = dd[i]["year"].unique()[0]
    plot = dd[i]['Journal Type'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=title);
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(str(title) + '.png')
```

However, it save the first figure and that's it. What I am doing wrong?
Any (more elegant) solution to the problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you mean `i =+ 1` to be `i += 1` ? (and do you really want to be incrementing that anyway? Also - is `i` meant to be the value in the dictionary or are you attempting to use a counter... the `i = 0` seems like the later but...)

Comment: I am indeed using i as counter to get dd[0], dd[1] etc. so yes, it should be i += 1, thanks I didn't noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to create a new figure every time, also, why don't you just loop through the `groupby`:

```
for title, data in df.groupby('year'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    data['Journal Type'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=title, ax=ax)
    fig.savefig(f'{title}.png')
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Using this I get the error ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [125], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for title, data in df.groupby('year'):
----> 2     fig, ax = plt.subplot()
      3     data['Journal Type'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=title, ax=ax)
      4     fig.savefig(f'{title}.png')

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object```

Comment: @K3it4r0 `subplots` not `subplot`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Small details, you forgot to add plot after value_counts() as `.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=title, ax=ax)`. As soon as you edit it I will mark the answer. Thanks again

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing out the error.